# Visualization for layered data

Tags: data-visualization

I have a dataset as attached. Four categories for income classes and three categories for the needs of these classes. The numbers show the percentages. I want to underline the percentages of these income classes for grocery, bakery and entertainment during the years. How can I visualise these data set within a graph? Any suggestions?

```
                Low income  mid-low mid income  high income

        Grocery    45         42       36           22
2010    Bakery     35         40       24           32
        Entert.    20         18       40           46
2011    Grocery    48         40       32           20
        Bakery     30         40       28           22
        Entert.    22         20       40           58
```

[image: data]

Comment: Can you please include the data as text, that is, a readable format, not as an image?

Comment: What is the main comparison you want to draw?  Do you want to see how grocery changes year over year, or how incomes differ within categories?  There are a lot of ways to plot this data, but I think if you tell is what you want to know about the data then that might help narrow it down.